# Outlook error: "Add-in still working" when sending message

Tags: javascript, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I've made a simple enough owa addin that, when the user launches it, a dialog window is opened (Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync) where the user can modify certain aspects of the message (affects recipients and mail headers). As far as i can tell, all the async requests complete nearly instantly when the user closes the dialog and the add-in completes its work, but the error is still triggered when attempting to send.

What seems to be the cause is that when the dialog is opened, owa starts spamming requests every second or so to an address that does not exist, and the error occurs until several minutes later the requests stop in what seems like a timeout of sorts.
My developer console is filled with this;

```
aria-web-telemetry.js:1 POST 
https://browser.pipe.aria.microsoft.com/Collector/3.0/?qsp=true&content- 
type=application%2Fbond-compact-binary&client-id=NO_AUTH&sdk-version=AWT-Web- 
JS-1.1.1&x-apikey=db334b301e7b474db5e0f02f07c51a47-a1b5bc36-1bbe-482f-a64a- 
c2d9cb606706-7439&client-time-epoch-millis=1532959882460 404 (Not Found)
```

So far google has not found me anything helpful, and i just cannot comprehend why Microsoft would be calling home to an address that doesn't exist.

Sure enough, https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted//ariatelemetry/aria-web-telemetry.js contains that url hardcoded. What can i do?

edit 1)

- I'm hosting my own trial windows server on a virtual machine, and using the exchange accounts of that server.
- The error occurs on all browsers.

  1. Firefox gives me `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://browser.pipe.aria.microsoft.com/Collector/3.0/?qsp=true&content-type=application%2Fbond-compact-binary&client-id=NO_AUTH&sdk-version=AWT-Web-JS-1.1.1&content-encoding=base64&x-apikey=a387cfcf60114a43a7699f9fbb49289e-9bceb9fe-1c06-460f-96c5-6a0b247358bc-7238&client-time-epoch-millis=1532965578192. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed).`
  2. IE does not really give me anything i can pick out
  3. The example above was from chrome
- I have not installed it on desktop, so only web so far.

As for code.
My manifest defines an action for a button control

```
    <Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
        <FunctionName>showMessageSecurityDialog</FunctionName>
    </Action>
```

that function in turn shows the dialog
`Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(window.location.origin + dialogPage, { height: 50, width: 75, displayInIframe: true }, dialogCallback);`

On the dialog, when the user presses the save button it runs
`Office.context.ui.messageParent(true);` to signal we're done

from here

```
    dialog = asyncResult.value;
    dialog.addEventHandler(
        Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, 
        messageHandler
    );
    dialog.addEventHandler(
        Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogEventReceived,
        eventHandler
    );
```

is called, which neatly flows into the message handler

```
dialog.close();
if (arg.message == true) {
    applyMessageSecurity();
}
```

applyMessageSecurity in turn runs a whole lot of async requests, and when the promises of those requests are resolved, i let the user know with `Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.addAsync("information", {type: "informationalMessage", persistent: false, message: "success"})`

afaik we should be done at this point. All the code is done running, the dialog is closed, yet, something in the background is still on causing owa to think the addin is running

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Could you please add some sample code showing what and how you're using the lib? Is this only happening on the web or does it also happen on the desktop? Is this an O365 or Outlook.com accound? Does it happen regardless of the browser you're using?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur good pointers. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure to call event.completed() after dialog closing or where your code finishes all of its work so that outlook can be notified that the current uiless code has been completed. You can find more details in [this article](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/manifest/functionfile?product=outlook).

Comment: Definitely a hassle to keep binding and passing the event forward, guess that is where i'll have to rethink some of the architecture. But calling it at the end of the chain seems to have worked. Thanks